# Word foldl' isn't optimized as well as Int foldl'

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

```
import Data.List

test :: Int -> Int
test n = foldl' (+) 0 [1..n]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ test $ 10^8
```

GHC optimizes the above code to the point that the garbage collector doesn't even have to do anything:

```
$ ghc -rtsopts -O2 testInt && ./testInt +RTS -s
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testInt.hs, testInt.o )
Linking testInt ...
5000000050000000
          51,752 bytes allocated in the heap
           3,480 bytes copied during GC
          44,384 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          17,056 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.101s  (  0.101s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.103s  (  0.102s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.1%  (0.1% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    511,162 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.8% of total user, 100.9% of total elapsed
```

However, if I change the type of `test` to `test :: Word -> Word`, then a lot of garbage is produced and the code runs 40x slower.

```
ghc -rtsopts -O2 testWord && ./testWord +RTS -s
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testWord.hs, testWord.o )
Linking testWord ...
5000000050000000
  11,200,051,784 bytes allocated in the heap
       1,055,520 bytes copied during GC
          44,384 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          21,152 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     21700 colls,     0 par    0.077s   0.073s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    4.551s  (  4.556s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.077s  (  0.073s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    4.630s  (  4.630s elapsed)

  %GC     time       1.7%  (1.6% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,460,957,186 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.3% of total user, 98.3% of total elapsed
```

Why does this happen? I expected the performance to be nearly identical?
(I'm using GHC version 8.0.1 on x86_64 GNU/Linux)

edit: I submitted a bug: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12354#ticket

Comment: What is the Core generated in both cases?

Comment: You should submit a bug to the GHC issue tracker (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket).

Comment: I submitted a bug: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12354#ticket

Comment: Here is the Int core http://pastebin.com/ixBhgMqc and the Word core http://pastebin.com/gtVeKjgX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably mostly, though not exclusively, due to rewrite rules that exist for Int and not Word.  I say that because if we use `-fno-enable-rewrite-rules` on the `Int` case we get a time that is much closer to, but not quite as bad as, the `Word` case.

```
% ghc -O2 so.hs -fforce-recomp -fno-enable-rewrite-rules && time ./so
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
5000000050000000
./so  1.45s user 0.03s system 99% cpu 1.489 total
```

If we dump the rewrite rules with `-ddump-rule-rewrites` and diff these rules then we see a rule that fires in the `Int` case and not the `Word` case:

```
 Rule: fold/build
 Before: GHC.Base.foldr
 ...
```

That particular rule is in Base 4.9 GHC.Base line 823 (N.B. I'm actually using GHC 7.10 myself) and does not mention `Int` explicitly.  I'm curious why it isn't firing for `Word`, but don't have the time right now to investigate further.

Comment: I haven't looked into it, but I'm placing my bet on the `Enum Word` instance being different from the `Enum Int` one, preventing the enumeration from being able to fuse with the `foldr`.

Comment: To start, the instance for `Word` usually converts the value to an `Integer` first, then converts the result back to `Word`.

Comment: Yeah, `fold/build` is hugely important. It's the optimization that eliminates the creation of the list in memory. It's quite probable that `Word`'s `Enum` implementation doesn't use `build`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by dfeuer in a comment here, the `Enum` instance for `Int` is better than the one for `Word`:

`Int`:

```
instance  Enum Int  where
    {-# INLINE enumFromTo #-}
    enumFromTo (I# x) (I# y) = eftInt x y

{-# RULES
"eftInt"        [~1] forall x y. eftInt x y = build (\ c n -> eftIntFB c n x y)
"eftIntList"    [1] eftIntFB  (:) [] = eftInt
 #-}
{- Note [How the Enum rules work]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
* Phase 2: eftInt ---> build . eftIntFB
* Phase 1: inline build; eftIntFB (:) --> eftInt
* Phase 0: optionally inline eftInt
-}

{-# NOINLINE [1] eftInt #-}
eftInt :: Int# -> Int# -> [Int]
-- [x1..x2]
eftInt x0 y | isTrue# (x0 ># y) = []
            | otherwise         = go x0
               where
                 go x = I# x : if isTrue# (x ==# y)
                               then []
                               else go (x +# 1#)

{-# INLINE [0] eftIntFB #-}
eftIntFB :: (Int -> r -> r) -> r -> Int# -> Int# -> r
eftIntFB c n x0 y | isTrue# (x0 ># y) = n
                  | otherwise         = go x0
                 where
                   go x = I# x `c` if isTrue# (x ==# y)
                                   then n
                                   else go (x +# 1#)
                        -- Watch out for y=maxBound; hence ==, not >
        -- Be very careful not to have more than one "c"
        -- so that when eftInfFB is inlined we can inline
        -- whatever is bound to "c"
```

Now `Word` actually uses the implementation for `Integer`

```
enumFromTo n1 n2       = map integerToWordX [wordToIntegerX n1 .. wordToIntegerX n2]
```

which uses

```
instance  Enum Integer  where
    enumFromTo x lim       = enumDeltaToInteger x 1     lim
```

Now `enumDeltaToInteger` has rewrite rules set up, but it turns out that `Word`’s `enumFromTo` is never inlined, so this setup has no chance of fusing here.

Copying this function into my test code causes GHC to inline it, the `fold/build` rule to fire, and cuts down allocation severely, but the conversion from and to `Integer` (which does allocate) remains.

Comment: The above is with 7.10. It should be slightly better with 8.0, where `remInteger` has become strict (See [#10691](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10691)).

Comment: Have you, or shall I, submitted a bug report to add a more efficient instance for Word?

Comment: Has already been done: [#12354](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12354#ticket)